# slowness of parser and need stanford-srparser models.jar pom entry

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using stanford corenlp jars in my java - vert.x application.
Dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

I am using below annotations

```
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, sentiment, lemma, ner");
```

Facing performance issues so trying to load below parsing model since as per  the documentation the shift reduce parser is faster

```
props.setProperty("parse.model","edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/ englishSR.ser.gz");
```

I need to add its above dependency separately and I see below jar mentioned most of the places but do not see its compatible or latest version and maven dependency:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar

Please assist at the earliest:   Not sure if adding the model englishSR.ser.gz directly on the classpath is a good idea, I am doing the same way for time being.

Even after using the SR model I do not see improvement in performance, can you please suggest ? I am trying to process pipeline for text I receive from chat bot [I am NOT trying to process file]
code snippet

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, sentiment, lemma, ner");  
props.setProperty("parse.model","edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
pipeline.process("this is my chat bot text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your models question: You could try this workaround. The GitHub version seems to request the 3.7.0 models, while the version ready to use is on 3.8.0....   Go to https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP , scroll down to "Build with Maven" and download the models you need, and include in your class path ...

Regarding performance: Consider avoiding the expensive setup by either processing more at once, or consider the server based approach, which is described here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Comment: Regarding performance: 

Can you please help me to understand how server based approach will help from Standford response perspective ? because it will be doing the same thing on the server what I am trying to do here. 
Also my current app primarily does the stanford NER extractions and Sentiment analysis.